# redirecionamento com o htacess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Galera configurei o meu htacess para pegar qualquer palavra que eu digitar na URL e procurar o arquivo php.

Funciona assim: www.meusite.com.br/Cidade e ele redireciona para www.meusite.com.br/Search/Cidade.php

O código esta assim:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) Search/$1.php/ [QSA,L]
```

Bom o que preciso fazer é, quando o arquivo não for achado, o htacess tem que mandar para página erro.html

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou fazer assim:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /erro.html
```

Assim, quando seu arquivo não for encontrado, o *htaccess* fará um redirecionamento para uma página de erro 404 personalizada ao invés da página default 404 do apache.

Comment: Fernando, podes explicar essa linha de código? Assim a resposta fica mais completa, senão é um comentário/pergunta somente...